# Does $elemMatch not work with a new mongodb 2.2?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In a new version on MongoDB we can use an $elemMatch projection operator to limit the response of a query to a single matching element of an array. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/

But it seems doesn't work yet in mongoose 3 here is the example:

```
{
 _id: ObjectId(5), 
 items: [1,2,3,45,4,67,9,4]
}

Folder.findOne({_id: Object(5)}, {$elemMatch: {$in: [1,67,9]}})
  .exec(function (err, doc) {

});
```

I'm expected to get the follows doc:

```
{
 _id: ObjectId(5), 
 items: [1,67,9]
}
```

But unfortunately what I'm getting is document with all items:

```
{
 _id: ObjectId(5), 
 items: [1,2,3,45,4,67,9,4]
}
```

Comment: @esaelPsnoroMoN This feature has been added in 2.2, as can be seen by the link given in the question. The OP also refers to the 2.2 version in the headline.

Comment: Perhaps in your findOne() call you need ObjectId(5) instead of Object(5)?

Comment: The same problem exists in MongoDB Node.JS Native Driver - you can set in options $elemMatch but driver returns always all subdocuments.
if you test your query in mongodb console it works great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mongodb docs here are misleading, we'll get them updated.

What its saying is that you can now use $elemMatch in your projection, that is, your field selection:

https://gist.github.com/3640687

See also: https://github.com/learnboost/mongoose/issues/1085

[Edit] pull request for docs sent: https://github.com/mongodb/docs/pull/185

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you are missing the `items` field name in front of the $elemMatch operator. Your query should read

```
Folder.findOne({_id: Object(5)}, {items: {$elemMatch: {$in: [1,67,9]}}})
  .exec(function (err, doc) { });
```

But this would still not return the desired result, because as stated in the documentation:

> The $elemMatch projection will only match one array element per source
>   document.

So you would only get back something like:

```
{
 _id: ObjectId(5), 
 items: [1]
}
```

Comment: You've forgotten the one more braces for 'items', the query should read: Folder.findOne({_id: Object(5)}, {items: {$elemMatch: {$in: [1,67,9]}}})
  .exec(function (err, doc) { });

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got mongoose set up to do this with node, but you can also get the result you want using the new aggregation framework in 2.2 - here's an example that gets you the result you wanted.  First, my sample doc looks like this:

```
> db.foo.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50472eb566caf6af6108de02"),
    "items" : [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        45,
        4,
        67,
        9,
        4
    ]
}
```

To get to what you want I did this:

```
> db.foo.aggregate( 
             {$match : {"_id": ObjectId("50472eb566caf6af6108de02")}},  
             {$unwind : "$items"},  
             {$match : {"items": {$in : [1, 67, 9]}}},  
             {$group : {_id : "$_id", items : { $push : "$items"}}},
             {$project : {_id : 0, items : 1}}
     )
{
    "result" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("50472eb566caf6af6108de02"),
        "items" : [
            1,
            67,
            9
        ]
    }
],
"ok" : 1

}
```

To explain, in detail I will take it line by line:

```
{$match : {"_id": ObjectId("50472eb566caf6af6108de02")}}
```

This is fairly obvious - it is basically the equivalent to the find criteria on a regular query, the results are passed to the next step in the pipeline to be processed.  This is the piece that can use indexes etc.

```
{$unwind : "$items"}
```

This will explode the array, creating a stream of documents, one for each element of the array.

```
{$match : {"items": {$in : [1, 67, 9]}}}
```

This second match will return only the documents in the list, basically reducing the stream of docs to a result set of three.

```
{$group : {_id : "$_id", items : { $push : "$items"}}}
```

We want our output to be an array, so we have to undo the unwind above now that we have selected the items we want, using the _id as the key to group.  Note: this will have repeating values if there is more than one match, if you wanted a unique list you would use `$addToSet` instead of `$push`

```
{$project : {_id : 1, items : 1}}
```

Then finally, this projection is not really needed, but I included it to illustrate the functionality - you could choose to not return the _id if you wished etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I think it's a bug of mongoose. And the using of aggregation framework to resolve my task is not good idea i think.

Comment: this is not a bug but a mongodb documentation issue. see my comment below.

Comment: @Erik - understood, I just wanted to offer you an alternative rather than a resolution to the mongoose/docs issue, I'd solved a similar issue the same way.